# Match two images taken with different cameras in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am using ChArUco markers in opencv with python. I have a set of images taken with two different different cameras with fisheye lenses.

This is one example of the images before any transformation:

[image]

Both cameras are calibrated and this is the image after it's been undistorted:

[image]

what I want to do next it to match the low resolution left image with the high resolution image on the right. The high res camera has a smaller FOV so it will fit in the low res image, as shown below

[image]

(As you can see from the above image the images don't match 100% since the two sensors are about 2cm apart, but that shouldn't be too much of an issue, once the system is set up, since pictures will be taken from a distance and the perspective difference should be neglectable)

My end goal is to have two images, one from the high res and one from the low res, with matching pixel coordinates

[image] [image]

What's the best way to accomplish this? Can I exploit the fact that I already have a bunch of pictures with the ChArUco board in frame? That would be great compared to a manual alignment

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: calibrate each camera intrinsically, then get the board pose in each camera's frame. or just find a homography given a bunch of points in common to both views.